# What do the various fields mean in an ssh identify file?

Tags: ssh, identity-management

So in `~/.ssh/config`, I see an identity file like the following.

```
Host github.com
  User gitboy
  Hostname github.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/some_public_github_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Is there some kind of specification that describes what these fields mean? (I can infer what they mean by being familiar with the github ssh process), but what does `IdentitiesOnly` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't an identity (public-key) file; it is a configuration file.  It is documented in the [ssh_config manual page](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config).  Alternately to web-hosted copies of manual pages, use `man ssh_config` on your local system to ensure that the documentation is for the version of `ssh` installed on your system.

---

The `IdentitiesOnly yes` line in particular indicates that the `ssh` connection should only use the specified `IdentityFile`; not any other identities which it might have access to.